# What is the fastest way to find longest 'consecutive numbers' streak in vector ?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, find

I have a sorted `std::vector<int>` and I would like to find the longest 'streak of consecutive numbers' in this vector and then return both the length of it and the smallest number in the streak.

To visualize it for you : 
suppose we have : 
`1 3 4 5 6 8 9`

I would like it to return: `maxStreakLength = 4` and `streakBase = 3`

There might be occasion where there will be 2 streaks and we have to choose which one is longer.

What is the best (fastest) way to do this ? I have tried to implement this but I have problems with coping with more than one streak in the vector. Should I use temporary vectors and then compare their lengths?

Comment: There is an easy to implement O(n) solution to this, which should not require an additional vector. I'm pretty sure there's an even faster method though, with a divide and conquer strategy. Is duplicates numbers possible?

Comment: @MarkRansom And? be it so. I don't fear contrived problems and this rather simple question still has much more algorithmic value than the most practically relevant "how make jQuery store an OpenGL into SQL using Facebook"-question.

Comment: @ChristianRau, the intent of such a question is either to get you to learn something or prove you already know it. Doing someone's thinking for them in such a situation is counter-productive, at least for that person.

Comment: @Lie Ryan: The fact that the input array is *sorted* immediately implies that the solver is supposed to take advantage of it. Linear solutions don't. I just posted a D&C solution that does. Maybe something more clever is possible.

Comment: @Patryk: Do you know in advance that all numbers in the array are unique?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you can do this in one pass through the vector and only storing the longest start point and length found so far. You also need much fewer  than 'N' comparisons. *

hint: If you already have say a 4 long match ending at the 5th position (=6) and  which position do you have to check next?

[*] left as exercise to the reader to work out what's the likely O( ) complexity ;-)

Comment: If you know that thy 5th and 6th position are different then I think you should examine the difference between 6th and 7th because there might be a new streak beginning. (unless you want to take `vector.size()` into consideration then you might just omit that because there won't be a longer streak in this `vector` anymore - but then you still make a comparison with `vector.size()` and number of remaining entries).

Comment: If you have already got a length=4 result then you are only interested in runs of 5 or more. So when you find the '8' in position 6 you should check position 6+5 to see if has the value 13 (=8+5). If it doesn't then there is no need to check the individual values between

Comment: @Martin: but you still need to look at the in between values.  For instance, you still need to check if a streak starts at position 7.

Comment: @KeithRandall - yes but you would check down from position 11, if the position before isn't X-1 then the intervening can't be a streak. As the current best gets longer the amount you can skip over gets bigger.

Answer (score 3):

It would be interesting to see if the fact that the array is sorted can be exploited somehow to improve the algorithm. The first thing that comes to mind is this: **if you know that all numbers in the input array are unique**, then for a range of elements `[i, j]` in the array, you can immediately tell whether elements in that range are consecutive or not, without actually looking through the range. If this relation holds

```
array[j] - array[i]  ==  j - i
```

then you can immediately say that elements in that range are consecutive. This criterion, obviously, uses the fact that the array is sorted and that the numbers don't repeat.

Now, we just need to develop an algorithm which will take advantage of that criterion. Here's one possible recursive approach:

1. Input of recursive step is the range of elements `[i, j]`. Initially it is `[0, n-1]` - the whole array.
2. Apply the above criterion to range `[i, j]`. If the range turns out to be consecutive, there's no need to subdivide it further. Send the range to output (see below for further details).
3. Otherwise (if the range is not consecutive), divide it into two equal parts `[i, m]` and `[m+1, j]`.
4. Recursively invoke the algorithm on the lower part (`[i, m]`) and then on the upper part (`[m+1, j]`).

The above algorithm will perform binary partition of the array and recursive descent of the partition tree using the left-first approach. This means that this algorithm will find adjacent subranges with consecutive elements in left-to-right order. All you need to do is to join the adjacent subranges together. When you receive a subrange `[i, j]` that was "sent to output" at step 2, you have to concatenate it with previously received subranges, if they are indeed consecutive. Or you have to start a new range, if they are not consecutive. All the while you have keep track of the "longest consecutive range" found so far.

That's it.

The benefit of this algorithm is that it detects subranges of consecutive elements "early", without looking inside these subranges. Obviously, it's worst case performance (if ther are no consecutive subranges at all) is still `O(n)`. In the best case, when the entire input array is consecutive, this algorithm will detect it instantly. (I'm still working on a meaningful O estimation for this algorithm.)

The usability of this algorithm is, again, undermined by the uniqueness requirement. I don't know whether it is something that is "given" in your case.

Anyway, here's a possible C++ implementation

```
typedef std::vector<int> vint;
typedef std::pair<vint::size_type, vint::size_type> range;

class longest_sequence
{
public:
  const range& operator ()(const vint &v)
  { 
    current = max = range(0, 0);

    process_subrange(v, 0, v.size() - 1);
    check_record();

    return max;
  }

private:
  range current, max;

  void process_subrange(const vint &v, vint::size_type i, vint::size_type j);
  void check_record();
};

void longest_sequence::process_subrange(const vint &v, 
                                        vint::size_type i, vint::size_type j)
{
  assert(i <= j && v[i] <= v[j]);
  assert(i == 0 || i == current.second + 1);

  if (v[j] - v[i] == j - i)
  { // Consecutive subrange found
    assert(v[current.second] <= v[i]);
    if (i == 0 || v[i] == v[current.second] + 1)
      // Append to the current range
      current.second = j;
    else
    { // Range finished
      // Check against the record 
      check_record();
      // Start a new range
      current = range(i, j);
    }
  }
  else
  { // Subdivision and recursive calls
    assert(i < j);
    vint::size_type m = (i + j) / 2;
    process_subrange(v, i, m);
    process_subrange(v, m + 1, j);
  }
}

void longest_sequence::check_record()
{
  assert(current.second >= current.first);
  if (current.second - current.first > max.second - max.first)
    // We have a new record
    max = current;
}

int main()
{
  int a[] = { 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 };
  std::vector<int> v(a, a + sizeof a / sizeof *a);
  range r = longest_sequence()(v);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Counterexample: `[2,2,2,4,4,4]`.  It does not contain consecutive elements, yet it satisfies `array[5] - array[0]  <=  5 - 0`.

Comment: @AndreyT - somehow my post about consecutive numbers has disapeared but I was trying to make the same point as Keith

Comment: @Keith Randall, Martin Beckett: You are right, it doesn't work at all, unless we know in advance that all numbers in the input array are not just sorted, but also unique. My mistake. Brainfart... Thank you for pointing it out. I added the uniqueness requirement to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this should do it?

```
size_t beginStreak = 0;
size_t streakLen = 1;
size_t longest = 0;
size_t longestStart = 0;
for (size_t i=1; i < len.size(); i++) {
    if (vec[i] == vec[i-1] + 1) {
        streakLen++;
    }
    else {
        if (streakLen > longest) {
            longest = streakLen;
            longestStart = beginStreak;
        }
        beginStreak = i;
        streakLen = 1;
    }
}
if (streakLen > longest) {
    longest = streakLen;
    longestStart = beginStreak;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't solve this problem in less than `O(N)` time.  Imagine your list is the first `N-1` even numbers, plus a single odd number (chosen from among the first `N-1` odd numbers).  Then there is a single streak of length 3 somewhere in the list, but worst case you need to scan the entire list to find it.  Even on average you'll need to examine at least half of the list to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Rodrigo's solutions but solving your example as well:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

#define len(x) sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0])

using namespace std;

int nums[] = {1,3,4,5,6,8,9};
int streakBase = nums[0];
int maxStreakLength = 1;

void updateStreak(int currentStreakLength, int currentStreakBase) {
  if (currentStreakLength > maxStreakLength) {
    maxStreakLength = currentStreakLength;
    streakBase = currentStreakBase;
  }
}

int main(void) {
  vector<int> v;
  for(size_t i=0; i < len(nums); ++i)
    v.push_back(nums[i]);

  int lastBase = v[0], currentStreakBase = v[0], currentStreakLength = 1;

  for(size_t i=1; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    if (v[i] == lastBase + 1) {
      currentStreakLength++;
      lastBase = v[i];
    } else {
      updateStreak(currentStreakLength, currentStreakBase);
      currentStreakBase = v[i];
      lastBase = v[i];
      currentStreakLength = 1;
    }
  }
  updateStreak(currentStreakLength, currentStreakBase);
  printf("maxStreakLength = %d and streakBase = %d\n", maxStreakLength, streakBase);

  return 0;
}
```